# Using relative urls when using "clean urls"?

Tags: php, relative-path, clean-urls

I direct all url requests to a front controller. The url requests look something like `example.com/controller/action/etc`. The problem is, using relative urls within the program. This works fine if there is only one slash in the url request, but if there is more than one slash, the relative url becomes broken.

At location `example.com/controller`, relative url `other-controller` works fine taking the user to `example.com/other-controller`.

At location `example.com/controller/action`, relative url `other-controller` doesn't work taking the user to `example.com/controller/other-controller`.

Any recommendations on how to get around this? Hoping I can do this without using absolute paths or some url generating code everytime I want to make a url in the app.

In case it matters, I am currently using this .htaccess code to redirect incomming requests to the front controller:

```
# Point all to index.php except existing files
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use absolute URLs to do what you want without looking at the current path you are at and adding the proper number of `..`s. You don't need to have the domain for each one, you can just use URLs like `/controller/action` and `/other-controller/action`. These will work for both controllers seamlessly. A sample anchor tag:

```
<a href="/controller/action">Do something!</a>
```

As a side note, oftentimes, people will write functions to generate URLs. If you are using a MVC framework, it may be in the form of adding a method to a model and call the function `get_absolute_url` which returns the form I mentioned above.

Comment: The opening slashed urls will work great. Only issue would be if I kept the app in a subfolder at any point... `example.com/someapp/controller/action`

Comment: That's true, but you could use `mod_rewrite` for that too :)